# My Angular app needs two columns, but the content of those can vary significantly based on the route. How do I approach setting up my components?

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, viewchild, ng-template

My app will always need two columns: one a bit smaller than the other. Currently in my main app component, the template is just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Currently, each of my routes directs to a different component, and each of these components are providing the markup for my two columns in it's own template. However, since my two columns will remain static throughout the app, it makes sense to me to provide the template for the columns at the root app level. This seems more modular, and wouldn't make for duplicate markup in templates throughout the app.

Here is an idea of the template I'd like in my root - right now this markup exist in each component that I route to:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="col three">

    </div>
    <div class="col nine">

    </div>
</div>
```

I get the feeling this is where I would utilize ngTemplateOutlet, or perhaps ngContent projection using "select", but I'm not sure if these things are applicable to my situation. The more I read about ng-template, the more confused I seem to get. Could I define this template as a TemplateRef and somehow access it in the child components?

Could anyone advise on the proper design strategy for this situation?

Comment: I'm really not sure to understand what you're doing unfortunately. But, it feels like you're looking for an aux route. If you want to manage both parts at the same time, with each of them their own urls, then auxiliary routes is the way to go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a solution.

My main app still simply has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for a template. Then I made a new component specifically for setting up my main template with the two columns. I'm using `ng-content` with `select` to project my content into the appropriate areas.

content-component.ts

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="col three">  
        <ng-content select="[leftColumn]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="col nine">
        <ng-content select="[rightColumn]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in each of my routed components, I'm wrapping them in my template component like so:

x-component.ts

```
<app-content-component>
    <div leftColumn>This is left content for x component</div>
    <div rightColumn>This is right content for x component</div>
</app-content-component>
```

I'm open to better solutions. I didn't necessarily want a whole new component to do this, and I don't like that I have to ensure this component is used in every template in my app, but for now it will at least allow me to make markup and styling changes to my columns in one location only.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 columns and each column should be based on router,
you can subscribe on `router.events` and then load components dynamically:

1. Put some logic in your controller

   ```
   myComponentLeft: any;
   myComponentRight: any;

   this.router.events.subscribe( (event : Event) => {
       if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
           // logic here. example:
           this.myComponentLeft = UsersComponent;
           this.myComponentRight = ProfileComponent;
       }
   });
   ```
2. NgComponentOutlet from your html

   ```
   <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myComponentLeft"></ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myComponentRight"></ng-container>
   ```

If you need to pass parameters to dynamic components, use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) instead of [ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)

Comment: While useful, I don't actually need multiple routes, nor do I want to route to multiple components at once. I need to route to one component at a time, and each component will have data and markup that would go into each column. I'm trying to set up only one template with two columns that I can reuse everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think that maxime1992's comment about aux routes is a good idea. That being said if your either of your columns have any functionality that affects the other column it may be a lot less work to just copy paste that markup on a few pages.

If you have Aux routes and theres heavy interaction between the two columns you may have to refactor a lot of code out to services or use event @Output to get the rendering system working properly.